# Как построить бинарное дерево?

Tags: mysql, бинарное-дерево, sql

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать бинарное дерево? У меня в `MySQL` есть такая таблица:

```
id | value
---+-------
 1 |   A
 2 |   DF
 3 |   BC
...
```

Значения в поле `value` можно (нужно) упорядочить. Но они добавляются в конец не по порядку. Как это можно осуществить?

Comment: так что должно быть в результате?

Comment: Хочу чтобы при SELECT * FROM `log` ORDER BY `что-то` он вывел мне значение `value`  по возрастанию.

Comment: ну так напишите  `SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY value`

Comment: А русские буквы он разберет?

Comment: да и с китайскими управится, главное правильно настроить базу.

Comment: Комментарий в ответ преобразуйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После долгих обсуждений, пришли к выводу, что `SELECT * FROM log ORDER BY value` будет ответом.  Плюс почитать что то в таком [стиле](http://dev.ezoterik.info/mysql-i-russkaya-kodirovka/).